# Python : sympy TypeError: can't convert expression to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, sympy, taylor-series

Currently, I'm working on a calculator, that works similar to a 'real' calculator, when determining definite integrals.

Currently i can get it to work with functions such as

- `sin(x)`
- `cos(x)`
- `e**x`
- `n*x**x`

However, it won't accept `math.sqrt(x)` as a function in my code, where it simply states, that

```
File "C:\Users\Nikolai Lund Kühne\.spyder-py3\integration.py", line 6, in <module>
  print(series(math.sqrt(x), x, x0=0, n=6))

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py", line 327, in __float__
  raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")

TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

My code is:

```
from sympy.functions import sin,cos
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import series
from pprint import pprint
# Indsæt her funktionen f(x), variablen x, udviklingspunktet x0 og antal led n
print(series(math.sqrt(x), x, x0=0, n=6))

N = int(input("Antal summer(flere summer er mere præcist): "))
a = int(input("Integrer fra: "))
b = int(input("Integrer til: "))

# Vi anvender Midpoint metoden til integration og skriver funktionen ind, som skal integreres

def integrate(N, a, b):
    def f(x):
        return series(math.sqrt(x), x, x0=0, n=6)
    value=0
    value=2
    for n in range(1, N+1):
        value += f(a+((n-(1/2))*((b-a)/N)))
    value2 = ((b-a)/N)*value
    return value2

print("...................")
print("Her er dit svar: ")
print(integrate(N, a, b))
```

Can anyone help me here, it's greatly appreciated.

Disclaimer: I am quite new to programming and Python and would appreciate any help given.
Sorry for the strange setup, I am used to LaTeX and MathJax when writing questions :)

Comment: Did you `import math`? Also `series` is only a module, you cannot use it as a function, if you want to use a function you have to import a specific function from this module e.g `from sympy import fourier_series`

Comment: Hey, `import math` doesn't seem to help, but i will include it. Okay, strangely it works with other functions as stated. I'm attempting to make python make a taylor series for a given function. Can you import a function from sympy or somewhere else like `from sympy import taylor_series` as a function?

Comment: Check out https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/series/series.html I think you're looking for the limit function, but read the doc yourself and checkout if thats what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error:

```
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Since the argument passed as `expr` is `math.sqrt(x)`, and `sympy` doesn't expect that.

Change from `math.sqrt(x)` to `x**0.5`:

```
print(series(x**0.5, x, x0=0, n=6))
```

The same applies to line 16.